# How to add two dataframes horizontally to one excel sheet in R

Tags: r, excel

I have the following dfs:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Engagement = c(1,1234,345,643,2345,645,687,9563,678,7), Post=c(6,8,65,34,23,4,67,8,9,6))
df2 <- data.frame(Tag=c("Love","Hope","Change","Faith","Doubt"),Count=c(521,502,378,95,33))
```

I'd like to add both to 1 excel sheet with a column between the two. I know there are ways to `rbind` the data and have a vertical offset so there's a space between them, but I want the dataframes to be next to each other. Is there a way to horizontally offset the data?

I currently have used `openxlsx` to write the larger df to excel and then manually have to put in the smaller ones. I'll be repeating this process often so any solution that isn't "copy/paste" is needed.

I have attached a picture of what I hope to have in excel for reference
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `xlsx`-package is your friend here

```
library( xlsx ) 

wb <- createWorkbook( type = "xlsx" )
sheet <- createSheet( wb, sheetName = "test" )

addDataFrame( df1, sheet, startRow = 1, startColumn = 1, row.names = FALSE )
addDataFrame( df2, sheet, startRow = 1, startColumn = 4, row.names = FALSE )

saveWorkbook( wb, "./example.xlsx" )
```

[image]